# Oracle Nested SUBSTR Compare

Tags: oracle, nested, substr, instr

I'm trying to query a table, and my criteria requires me to match a literal with a substring of a column, like this:

```
SELECT .........
FROM issuer_table
WHERE owner = "ABC"
  AND {substr logic} = v_cik_nbr;
```

My column values are like this:  "http://www.url.com/data/Archives/931015/000120767912044794/doc4.xml"

So, I've been playing with statements like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(x,1,INSTR(x,'/')-1)
FROM (SELECT SUBSTR('http://www.url.com/data/Archives/931015/000120767912044794/doc4.xml',
              INSTR('http://www.url.com/data/Archives/931015/000120767912044794/doc4.xml','/',1,7) +1) AS x
      FROM dual);
```

So, that actually gets me the value I need to compare against:  "000120767912044794".  But, how to incorporate that into the WHERE clause?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: Your test statement returns `null`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d8c18a2b9067070ef204c06d67764293

Answer (score 0):

Your substr isn't quite right if it's supposed to return 000120767912044794 in your example. If you want to return from between the second last and the last '/' then your inner instr needs to be instr(expression,'search',-1,2) - start from the end and return the second match.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(x,1,INSTR(x,'/')-1)
FROM (
SELECT SUBSTR('http://www.url.com/data/Archives/931015/000120767912044794/doc4.xml',
              INSTR('http://www.url.com/data/Archives/931015/000120767912044794/doc4.xml','/',-1,2) +1) AS x
FROM dual
)
```

To use it as an expression in your query you would copy the expression into your main substr so that it can be used at the same level:

```
SUBSTR(SUBSTR(my_url,INSTR(my_url,'/',-1,2) +1),1,INSTR(SUBSTR(my_url,INSTR(my_url,'/',-1,2) +1),'/')-1)
```

Which then makes your query

```
SELECT .........
FROM issuer_table
WHERE owner = "ABC"
  AND SUBSTR(SUBSTR(my_url,INSTR(my_url,'/',-1,2) +1),1,INSTR(SUBSTR(my_url,INSTR(my_url,'/',-1,2) +1),'/')-1) = v_cik_nbr;
```

Alternatively, you could take the hit and use regexp:

```
SELECT .........
FROM issuer_table
WHERE owner = "ABC"
  AND regexp_substr(my_url,'.*\/([^\/]*)/[^\/]*',1,1,'i',1) = v_cik_nbr;
```

The substr/instr expression can be indexed, the regexp one can't be (as it can have non-deterministic behaviours)

Answer (score 0):

Wrong approach.

Suppose you must compare a long string like `'abcdef/0123456789/blahblahblah/etc'` to the string `'0123456789'`. One way is to play silly tricks with `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`, or regular expressions, or whatnot. Another, simpler way is to, instead, use the FULL string and compare it against the string of digits, using the `LIKE` operator with wildcards.

It would look like this:

```
... where <string> LIKE '%/0123456789/%'
```

Here `%` is a wildcard (standing for any string at all), and `/` has no special meaning. Including `/` on both sides of the digit-string we ensure that the required fragment doesn't appear as a substring of the desired `v_cik_number`, but instead it is the full such number.

In your case, something like:

```
where <string> like '%/' || v_cik_number || '/%'
```

assuming that `v_cik_number` is in fact a **string** and not a number; if it is a number, you must handle leading zeros, which is not difficult, you just must know ahead of time what the total length of a "v_cik_number" string is supposed to be. And assuming, of course, that the `v_cik_number` must appear enclosed by forward slashes, and it cannot be confused with some other substring of the URL.